# After login what needs to happen to pull a user's profile from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express

I am using nodejs and mongodb. I have the login process working correctly, and have a good idea on how sessions work. I am just confused of what has to happen next after the user logs in to pull the user's profile from the db? I have the loginPost that sends that authenticates a user and if no error it redirects them currently to another page called userProfile. However, how do I pull the user's actual profile from the db? Am I suppose to query the db after login or during the loginPost function or does it have to happen on the new page I call which is a simple exports.userProfile page rendering the jade file?

Here is the code that I use for the loginPost:

```
exports.loginPost = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('loginError'); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }        
      return res.redirect('userProfile');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

UPDATE to include session:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());

app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'this is a secret'

    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both options can be considered. Howerver, if you want the rendering function/module to be light, query to pull the user info during the loginPost function and add those informations to exports.

Comment: Ok if I query it during the loginPost function i.e. nesting an if statement that states if the credentials are correct, do I query the email used to login or is there a session ID created somehow that has to be queried? Also, how does the userProfile know about the query during the loginPost to be able to render the information onto the page?  I actually do not understand that part of the sessions, of how to connect it to a user? All I have up for the session code will be updated in the question.

Comment: I do not not how your data are structured. However, if you can check the credentials from the DB, it means you can also get information about the user, for example the user_id. And use that id for the subsequent queries. For the session ID, I do not know if you have to manage it by yourself or if mongo has a mechanism for that. If you still have question, do not hesitate, I will answer the one that I can answer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense I guess the confusing part is whether or not I need to use the session ID at all, instead of querying based on the credentials originally posted.  If you know what I am suppose to do with the session ID if anything? Otherwise I am assuming as the login form is posted that I can query the body aka post of the login form from the db to draw out the user's profile. I just do not know how to go about querying for a person if I a user logs in is redirected to another page, how do I pull his info then, I am assuming that part has to do with the session ID, which I need help on.

Comment: The sessionID should be a key between the server and the user browser. When the user first connects to the app, the server (your app) generates the session id and send it back the browser and the browser send it back to the server anytime the user navigates to some other page. When you app creates that session ID, it also creates a record to identify the user, and that record contains everything you need to provide all other informations to the user. If you did not write the part of the application that generate the session record, check its definition to see what it contains.